# Calculate Smith Normal Form

Tags: smith-normal-form

Let \begin{align*}
    A=\begin{pmatrix}
    1&0&-1&2\\
    1&2&1&0\\
    1&0&2&2\\
    1&2&2&0
    \end{pmatrix} \in \mathbb{Z}^{4\times 4}
\end{align*}
Calculate the Smith normal form

---

\begin{align*}
    A &\leadsto \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0 & -1 & 2 \\
    0 & 2 & 2 & -2 \\
    0 & 0 & 3 & 0 \\
    0 & 2 & 3 & -2
    \end{pmatrix} \leadsto \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 2 & 2 & -2 \\
    0 & 0 & 3 & 0 \\
    0 & 2 & 3 & -2
    \end{pmatrix}
    \leadsto \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 3 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 0
    \end{pmatrix} 
\end{align*}

$3\nmid 1$, so what do I have to do next? I'm pretty sure I already messed up, because according to a calculator, I should have
$$\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0
    \end{pmatrix} $$
at the end. Can somebody explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your steps are fine, but your matrix is not in Smith normal form. We could further reduce your matrix as follows.

$$
\pmatrix{
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 3 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 0} \leadsto
\pmatrix{
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 3 & 0} \leadsto
\pmatrix{
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0} \leadsto\\
\pmatrix{
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0} \leadsto 
\pmatrix{
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0}.
$$